# How do I create a Counter-Strike 1.6 FFA server?

Tags: counter-strike

How do I create a Counter-Strike 1.6 Free For All server? We are three friends and we want to play a FFA death match on LAN. Is there any map for that?

Answer (score 2):

Download and install the following:

#### - [AMX Mod X](http://www.amxmodx.org/downloads.php) [ installation instructions: [automatic](http://wiki.amxmodx.org/Installing_AMX_Mod_X_Automatically), [manual](http://wiki.amxmodx.org/Installing_AMX_Mod_X_Manually) ]

#### - [Counter-Strike Deathmatch](http://www.bailopan.net/csdm/index.php?page=download) [ [installation instructions](http://www.bailopan.net/csdm/index.php?page=install) ]

---

You'll want to use a listen server (started using `New Game`) instead of a dedicated server, so be sure to choose that in the AMX Mod X installer if you are using the automatic installation method.

After you have installed everything, configure both [AMX Mod X](http://wiki.amxmodx.org/Configuring_AMX_Mod_X) and [Counter-Strike Deathmatch](http://www.bailopan.net/csdm/index.php?page=doc#configs), **if needed**.